# optimizing rewrite rule in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

I am using following wp functions to show a user profile:

```
add_action( 'init', 'rewrite_function' );
function rewrite_function()
{ 
    add_rewrite_tag('%user%', '([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^user/([0-9]+)/?',
        'index.php?user=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
};


add_action( 'template_redirect', 'rewrite_template' );
function rewrite_template()
{
    if( get_query_var( 'user' ) )
    {
        add_filter( 'template_include', function() {
            return get_template_directory() . '/user_profile.php';
        });
    }
};
```

And user_profile.php has the follwoing: (Just for the testing purpose)

```
<?php 
/* Template Name: User profile*/ 
get_header(); 
?>

<div class="sdfsdf">
<?php 
    global $wp_query;
    echo 'User : ' . $wp_query->query_vars['user']; 
?>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

So, if a user goes to  `example.com/user/1`, then it goes through these functions to show the user profile.

Everything works fine.

However, I am noticing some delay in loading the page. Although the user_profile.php doesn't have any content other than showing the user id, it generally takes about 1 to 2 sec. Whereas the main page takes less than 1 sec. I could use JSON to restructure the functions and paths, but I was wondering if the rewrite functions above are optimized.

Any thoughts?